# App Icon not showing on devices with android version greater than 4.4.2

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Working on an android Project with Android Studio 3.0 canary 3.
Everything is working fine except the app icon not displaying on devices with 
android version greater than 4.4.2.

Below is the Manifest Code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tanamo.dicto">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name="com.tanamo.dicto.ui.Flash"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

             <activity
            android:name="com.tanamo.dicto.ui.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="e37648ec32244464a260f2ec74053af82bfd1335" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: are u sure have u added different resolution of images in @mipmap

Comment: Yes i have @ Anil

Comment: make sure you are using:
192*192 for xxxhdpi
144*144 for xxhdpi
96*96 for xhdpi
72*72 for hdpi
58*58 for mdpi

Comment: also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39434020/7679573)

Comment: Did that already @ Shevchuk

Comment: The source code is below  https://github.com/Tanamo-Inc/Dicto

Comment: Thanks Guys.I have resolve the issue now by deleting the ic_launcher from android studio 3.0 canary.I created new one using android studio 2.3.3.Works now.