# Android Gradle v 3.1.3 update turned app launcher icon to default

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

After I updated my build.gradle with 
`com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3`

The icon of my app shows up as default android Icon.

I am using correct icon and round icon in my AndroidManifest.xml as below

```
 <application
    android:name=".EbatesApp"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/application_name"
    android:resizeableActivity="false"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_circle"
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:allowBackup,android:supportsRtl,label"
    >
```

I have `mipmap-anydpi` that has `ic_launcher.xml` and `ic_launcher_circle.xml`

And that subsequently calls appropriate pngs from mipmap folders based on resolution.

This works only for the devices that has Android O+.

All this was working fine till gradle v 2.3.3. However after update this doesn't seem to work.

I have searched on SO and found similar post [App icon doesn't show (Android Studio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39433994/app-icon-doesnt-show-android-studio) ,  but that doesn't work for me.

No word on it in migrartion guide either: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration

Any inputs on what seems to missing would be greatly appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually the same as this post:
[Application icon not showing after Gradle plugin update to 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47869707/application-icon-not-showing-after-gradle-plugin-update-to-3-0/51092149#51092149)

This is not specific to v3.1.3, but v3.0.0 in general. The solution is to change from **mipmap-anydpi** -> **mipmap-anydpi-v26**.

Comment: Thanks @vhuynh! I was going crazy on this.

Comment: It would have been nice of migration guide would mention something about it