# Android project doesn't generate a launcher icon

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-icons

first, i ran my project it didn't because of leak of storage problem . so  i freed some space then it went well , but no launcher icon appears on my desktop

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".Start"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SongsList"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".FirstSong"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
</application>
```

........

these're the lines that do the work

Comment: can you please add screen shot of android studio project panel with mipmap dir ?

Answer (score 0):

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39433994/app-icon-doesnt-show-android-studio) for more details. Or Create a valid icon using [this](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html)

Also check your Intent Filter.

```
 <activity
    android:name=".Start"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

You should use a single `intent filter` with `action` and `category` inside it, instead of two splitted intent filter, that is

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: @AliK. Did it install successfully?

Comment: no i failed   i created a new project to get a launcher for my code

Comment: @AliK. Post that failure, for example the compiler error output and logcat.

Comment: @AliK. Does the application listed in System Settings?

Comment: "DId it install successfully?" "No, I failed..." Then there must be an error. Post it.